# css font-face with the Arabic fonts

Tags: css, font-face

I'm trying to use an [Arabic external font](http://en.fonts2u.com/ge-ss-tv-bold.czcionka):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "My";
    src: url(GE_SS_TV_Bold.otf) format("truetype");
}
p.customfont { 
    font-family: "My", Verdana, Tahoma;
}
```

It's appearing like this:
[image]
but it should appear like:[image]

Comment: Can you paste the characters in plain text here (not an image) so people can play with them?

Answer (score 2):

hmmm… what is the browser you are using, what is the operating system your are using. [Font Faces](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/beautiful-fonts-with-font-face/) have different rendering depending on the platform/software.

Also in your document you seem to mix truetype and opentype ;) otf = OpenType Font, ttf = TrueType font usually. What about if you rewrite like?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "My";
    src: url(GE_SS_TV_Bold.otf) format("opentype");
}
```

if you need  one font in different formats and you have the files

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "My";
    src: url(GE_SS_TV_Bold.otf) format("opentype"),
    src: url(GE_SS_TV_Bold.ttf) format("truetype");
}
```