# How setup arabic configuration for Android 2.2 emulator

Tags: javascript, html, android-emulator

I'm developing a cross platform mobile web-app for android, iphone
I want to display some titles in arabic
I dont intend to convert the device language, I just want to view those titles properly.

Comment: Don't forget to set the [`lang` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-lang-and-xml:lang-attributes) appropriately on those title elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a web-app, I would suggest to use css3 in combination with WebFonts. Here's another question with regard to Arabic fonts
[css font-face with the Arabic fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928730/css-font-face-with-the-arabic-fonts)