# harmonizing arabic font across browsers

Tags: html, css, fonts

while working on an international website, i'm confronted to an inconsistency, the font size differ on chrome/ff on the display of the arabic font, that i can't seem to fix in css only (base size of the font are differents so i can't fix them for all of them).

do you know a way to do that without JS, or should I make separate css with browser agent detection ?

thanks

Comment: Hope you can fix it 
see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928730/css-font-face-with-the-arabic-fonts and will help some

Answer (score 0):

i found that my problem was related to the lack of italic variant on my arabic font, i now have a consistent view on all cases